# Programs that import 3ds max files

Tags: 3d-modeling, 3ds-max

What programs (other than 3ds max itself) can import and render a 3ds max file? I'd prefer a program that is free or open source if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

A `.max` file can be imported into most Autodesk programs (Maya, AutoCAD, etc.) and can be exported to a `.obj` format by 3dsmax, then opened in almost every 3D modelling program in existence. All of Autodesk’s programs are available for free from their website on a student or educational license, however with that license you cannot use your creations for commercial gain.

I believe programs such as Mudbox, Softimage, ZBrush, etc. can also open `.max` files.

Answer (score 1):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) is FOSS

Answer (score 1):

There are many 3d apps that can import the .*3ds* and .*dxf* formats, which Max can export to. I don't believe there's anything other than Max that can read actual .*max* files because of the nature of that format (it's heavily dependent on the plug-ins utilized in constructing the scene).

Source:
http://wiki.cgsociety.org/index.php/3ds_Max_File_Formats

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an online app that can import a .Max file and export it to FBX, .OBJ and .STL. I tested it out. I was able to load the .obj file it produced into Blender. I don't know how well that worked, because I don't know a lot about Blender - it seemed to work, but didn't look right. I loaded the .obj file it produced into Element 3D (running inside of After Effects, and it seemed to work OK - missing the textures.)

[MAX to FBX Converter](https://anyconv.com/max-to-fbx-converter/)

And found that FreeCad is supposed to be to import the .Max file with the use of this add on: [FreeCad addon or macro: Importer3D](https://github.com/jmplonka/Importer3D)

I haven't been able to install this Importer3D into FreeCad to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Rhinoceros](http://www.rhino3d.com/) can, for one. Unfortunatelly, neither free, nor open source, but worth every eurocent otherwise.

As far as one can see, with appropriate plugins so can [Inventor](http://www.sycode.com/products/3ds_import_iv/index.htm), [Solidworks](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/3ds-import-for-solidworks.htm), and *lady* [Maya](http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/tutorials/import-export/c/3ds-import-into-maya).

I haven't used much that format (other suited me better), but it is a rather *common* format, nothing out of the ordinary. I gather most stronger ones would be able to load it, if not natively, then through a plugin or an add-on.